# Include Jacoco repots in Maven site

Tags: maven, plugins, jacoco

I've integrated the `jacoco-maven-plugin` in my project, based on this excellent guide: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

The Jacoco plugin runs fine. However, the `maven-site-plugin` does not include the Jacoco reports in the site. To be more specific: the 'Project Reports' section does not list the Jacoco reports. The Jacoco reports themselves are available in the `target/site/jacoco-ut` and `target/site/jacoco-it` directories.

Here's what I did (without success so far).

First, included the `jacoco-maven-plugin` as a plugin in the `build` section of my `pom.xml`, as explained in the guide referenced above. I'm using Jacoco version 0.6.4.201312101107.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- scissors... -->
    <!-- report goal is bound to the pre-site phase -->
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Second, included the `jacoco-maven-plugin` in the `report` section of my `pom.xml`: no success.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Third, tried to add a `reportsets` section to the `jacoco-maven-plugin` in the `report` section: no success.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
  <reportSets>
    <reportSet>
      <reports>
        <report>report</report>
      </reports>
    </reportSet>
  </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

Can anyone help me to make the `maven-site-plugin` reference the coverage reports generated by Jacoco in the 'Project Reports' section of the site?

Answer (score 4):

I've found jacoco to be very tricky, the below config worked for me, i put it together from bits and pieces from blogs
in the properties

```
<jacoco.reportPath>${main.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</jacoco.reportPath>
    <jacoco.itReportPath>${main.basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.itReportPath>
```

inside the build

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.4.201312101107</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                            <propertyName>utCoverageAgent</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                            <propertyName>itCoverageAgent</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

       <!-- Reporting plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.site.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <attach>true</attach>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>range</type>
                            <range>1</range>
                            <!--<displayFileDetailUrl>${project.scm.url}/tree/master/%FILE%</displayFileDetailUrl>-->
                            <headingDateFormat>MM-dd-yyyy</headingDateFormat>
                            <outputEncoding>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</outputEncoding>

                        </configuration>
                        <reports>
                            <report>changelog</report>
                        </reports>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                            <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                        </configuration>
                        <!-- simpler configuration without reportSets available for usual cases -->
                        <!-- distribution-management, index, dependencies, help, issue-tracking, plugins, cim,
                        license, dependency-management, mailing-list, project-team, dependency-convergence,
                        scm, plugin-management, modules, summary -->
                        <reports>
                            <report>index</report>
                            <report>dependencies</report>
                            <report>issue-tracking</report>
                            <report>scm</report>
                            <report>summary</report>
                        </reports>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.1</version>
                            <reports>
                                <report>javadoc</report>
                                <report>aggregate</report>
                            </reports>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.4.201312101107</version>
                    </plugin>

                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: as of mvn 3.0.4 you can't use the configuration->reportPlugins tag of the maven-site-plugin anymore. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#Configuration_formats

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

You have been quite close to the solution, but

- a section `report` does not exist in `pom.xml`, you need `reporting` (maybe just misspelled?)
- `reportSets` is not a property of `build -> plugins -> plugin` either, but of `reporting -> plugins -> plugin`.

So in order to have the JaCoCo report in the generated Maven site, you will specify the JaCoCo Maven plugin twice:

1. Under `build -> plugins -> plugin` to enable the Java agent (no need to add the `report` goal here).
2. `reporting -> plugins -> plugin` to specify the `reportSet`.

The most simple snippet is:

```xml
    <!-- goes directly under tag "project" -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.plugin.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

## Long Answer

Although it is also possible to manually add a link to the JaCoCo report through customizing the output of `maven-site-plugin` (e.g. through `site.xml`), this is not the easiest and not the intended way. JaCoCo's `ReportMojo` implements `MavenMultiPageReport`, which allows the `maven-site-plugin` to detect it as reporting plugin. However just by reading the documentation it is far from obvious how it works.

When specifying the `report` goal under `build -> plugins` the `maven-site-plugin` has no clue the JaCoCo report exists. Only when given under `reporting -> plugins`, and there it is called `report` instead of `goal`, although it is actually the same thing. When specified here, the (reporting) plugin will be started through `maven-site-plugin` indirectly (and not directly through the Maven build).

However for the report to have the necessary information, the JaCoCo output must exist before reporting, and this is only the case when the goal `prepare-agent` (or `prepare-agent-integration` for integration tests) has been added to the `jacoco-maven-plugin` under `build -> plugins`. Phew!

[JaCoCo](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) has three reports (which can be triggered both ways):

- `report` for a single Maven project
- `report-aggregate` for a multi-module Maven project
- `report-integration` for integration tests

All of them are detected (and also executed in case `reportSet` is omitted) by the `maven-site-plugin` automatically:

```
[INFO] --- site:3.12.1:site (default-site) @ java-playground ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.11
[INFO] 3 reports detected for jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.11: report, report-aggregate, report-integration
```

Long story short, a complete pom.xml for a simple single Maven project might look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-playground</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- no explicit report generation here!
                         (commented for illustration purposes)
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <!-- whatever you use for your tests -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The outcome will look like this:
[image]

See also:

- [Apache Maven Reporting Executor](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-reporting-exec/)
- [Apache Maven Site Plugin - Configuring Reports](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html)
- [JaCoCo Maven Plugin](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html)
  (look for "*Usage of plugin together with maven-site-plugin*")

Answer (score 0):

What I did was merge the two execution files (`jacoco-ut.exec` and `jacoco-it.exec`) into a single file named `jacoco.exec` and then set that file as the `dataFile` of the plugin.

First, let's define these properties:

```xml
<jacoco.it.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.it.execution.data.file>
<jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>
<jacoco.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</jacoco.execution.data.file>
```

Then, along with the configuration to generate the reports, include this snippet to create the merged file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        ...
        <execution>
            <id>merge</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.exec</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
                <destFile>${jacoco.execution.data.file}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report-merge</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${jacoco.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And, finally, configure the plugin in the `reporting` section to generate the report from that merged file:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${jacoco.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```