JaCoCo always generates aggregate report in a non-module project, won't display coverage in Maven Site
I have a single Java 11 library (jar) project whose Maven pom refers to a parent pom for common properties and configuration.  There are no submodules and the parent pom doesn't have any submodules.  The parent pom contains a <pluginManagement> section.  Both the parent pom and the project pom contain configuration for Jacoco, and as expected, the project pom overrides the parent.  My parent pom doesn't have a Jacoco entry in the <reporting> section.
What I'm trying to do:
Generate the link to the Jacoco report in the project's Maven Site.
What's happening:
Running mvn clean test site generates a complete Jacoco coverage report against the project's unit tests in target/site/jacoco directory but isn't linked in the Project Reports.  Instead a Jacoco Aggregate link always appears and displays an empty report.  The Jacoco data file is being generated in the correct location.  The target/site/jacoco-aggregate folder contains only a few files including an index.html.
What I've attempted
I've tried a number of things to create the link, and from reading various articles (e.g. empty aggregate report with parent pom, and Jacoco Report are not generated in the site) and the JaCoCo documentation , I've learned that all of the Jacoco reports will generate automatically unless a specific report is configured in the <reporting> section, which was only the report report.  I also moved the Jacoco plugin from the <build><pluginManagement> section in the parent pom into the <build> section (of the parent pom), since that can supposedly cause the plugin to think this is a module project but that didn't solve it.  I've also tried commenting out various tags that customize the plugin but removing them hasn't enabled the report report.  The only customization I can't turn off is the prepare-agent and report goals.
Console output
The console does show this warning but I see it in projects even when it's working correctly.
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

Parent pom
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    ...
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.11</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
            <propertyName>argline.jacoco</propertyName>
            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/code-coverage/data/jacoco.exec</destFile>
            <includes>
              <include>${jacoco.include}</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>${jacoco.exclude}</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-report</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/code-coverage/data/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/code-coverage/report</outputDirectory>
          <includes>
            <include>${jacoco.include}</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>${jacoco.exclude}</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>

Project pom
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.11</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
</reporting>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${version.jacoco}</version>
      <executions>
        <!-- first execution : for preparing JaCoCo runtime agent -->
        <execution>
          <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <!-- second execution : for creating code coverage reports -->
        <execution>
          <id>default-report</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <configuration>
            <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/code-coverage/data/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/site/jacoco</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
              <include>${jacoco.include}</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>${jacoco.exclude}</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</build>


I could configure the maven-site-plugin to manually add a "Jacoco" link but I shouldn't have to do that.

This was informative but didn't solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048776/include-jacoco-repots-in-maven-site

I recommend to check here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/example-jacoco and https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/10/2023-10-26-maven-jacoco-configuration/ I strongly recommend to remove all the unnecessary configurations instead of using defaults...

@khmarbaise If I remove various configurations then the plugin will assume the default, right?  I don't quite understand, "instead of using defaults."  That is, I think I'm using the defaults where I'm not configuring it.

You are also configuring things which not required to be configured ... use the defaults first...

Solved
I figured out that it was two-fold:

the reporting section (of my project pom) needed a reference to the data file, specifically:

    <plugin>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/code-coverage/data/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
        ...
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>


Maven needed to be invoked with the test phase

These customizations were being specified in my root and project poms so I needed to provide JaCoCo with additional guidance about these customizations.  Sometimes you're in a situation where you don't have the reach to remove customizations, you have to make what's given to you work.
